# Не корректная конвертация цвета из формата HEX в INT на php

Tags: php, hex

Нужно конвертировать цвет из формата HEX в INT. Некоторые значения конвертируются правильно, но большинство нет. Вот код:

```
$color = '#0080c0'; 
function hex2int16($str) {
$num = hexdec($str);
return ($num & 0x80) ? $num - 65536 : $num;
}
echo hex2int16($color);
```

Вот пример неправильной конвертации оранжевого цвета, при сохранении такое вот значение -32576.

Comment: Простая функция `hexdec`, только строка нужна без `#`

Comment: @Let's say Pi А возможно получить сначала из HEX в RGB, а после в int?

Comment: ```echo hexdec(str_replace("#", "", "#0080c0"));``` - в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: @Альберт, написал ответ

Answer (score 0):

И так, вы хотите сделать конвертацию из `HEX` в `RGB`, а затем из `RGB` в `Integer`.

В качестве примера рассмотрим значение, изначально зная результаты всех конвертаций, чтобы потом сравнить результаты выполнения функций.

`HEX` — `#0080c0` | `RGB` - `0, 128, 192` | `INT` - `32960`

*Во-первых*, напишем функцию конвертации из `HEX` в `RGB`:

```
$color = '0080c0';

function hex2rgb($hex)
{
    list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex, "%02x%02x%02x");
    return [$r, $g, $b];
}

print_r(hex2rgb($color));
```

Результатом будет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 128
    [2] => 192
)
```

*Во-вторых*, напишем функцию конвертации из `RGB` в `INT`:

```
function rgb2int($rgb)
{
    return (($rgb[0] & 0xff) << 16) + (($rgb[1] & 0xff) << 8) + ($rgb[2] & 0xff);
}
```

И протестируем сразу две функции:

```
echo rgb2int(hex2rgb($color));
```

Результат будет integer `32960`, то, что мы и хотели получить.